# Keep VStack in center of the screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm new on SwiftUI and I don't know how to manage my views.

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var passord: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Image("corner")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
            
            VStack {
                VStack  { //VStack1
                    
                    TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 40)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .bold(true)
                    SecureField("Password", text: $passord)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 40)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .bold(true)
                    Button {
                        //Do something
                    } label: {
                        Text("Forgot your password ?")
                            .underline()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                
                VStack { // VStack2
                    Text("Not registered ?")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Button("Sign up") {}
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 37)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color(.orange))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I want to place the `VStack2` in the bottom of the screen and keep the `VStack1` on the center of the screen.

How I can do that. I've try to search but I don't find the solution on StackOverflow.

I tried to play with Spacer() and padding() but I have not a good result.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYvHg.jpg)

Comment: The new “Layout” can help you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to add `VStack1` to the `ZStack` which will place it in the centre of the screen. Then add wrap `VStack2` in another `VStack` with a `Spacer` to push it to the bottom of the screen, e.g.

```
ZStack {
    Image("corner")
    
    VStack  { //VStack1
        // etc
    }

    VStack {
        Spacer()
        
        VStack { // VStack2
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple put

```swift
HStack {
  Spacer()
  VStack {
    Text("Centered")
  }
  Spacer()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var passord: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Spacer()
            middleView()
            Spacer()
            bottomView()
            .paddind(.bottom, 12)
         }
         .ignoresSafeArea()
         .background {
          Image("corner")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
         }

    }

    func middleView() -> some View {

        VStack(spacing: 20)  {  
           TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 40)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .bold(true)

           SecureField("Password", text: $passord)
                      .frame(width: 300, height: 40)
                      .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                      .bold(true)

            Button {
                        //Do something
             } label: {
                 Text("Forgot your password ?")
                      .underline()
                      .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
             } 
    }


    func bottomView() -> some View() {
      VStack { 

                    Text("Not registered ?")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Button("Sign up") {}
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 37)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color(.orange))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                }
    }

}
```